# Enabling Location mode High Accuracy or Battery saving, programmatically, without user needing to visit Settings

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, android-location, android-settings

***Why i ask this:***(also the reason for trying it in an app)

**It happens** when we use **Google Maps in Lollipop**. *Even if the Location is disabled, it is turned on, in high accuracy mode after user's input from the Maps app, without having to visit Settings.*

A similar functionality can be achieved for enabling Bluetooth, where the action is initiated in my app; user needs to make a choice but user is not redirected to Settings, using:

`startActivity(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));`

which could be found on [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), now we know there is no LocationAdapter, so i looked around [gms->LocationServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html), basically almost everything under [Location API references](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html), [android.location.LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) but doesn't seem anything like `ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` is available as yet.

Hope there is some other method for the same, and more people have tried it.

Please note:
`context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));` does not work like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

***UPDATE 3***:

***[Prompt the user to change location settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings#prompt)***
as @patrickandroid, mentioned in comments, the link from second update is broken

***[GoogleSamples; android Location and options - for code reference.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)***

***UPDATE 2***:

***[GoogleSamples; - for code reference.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationSettings)***

> This sample builds on the LocationUpdates sample included in this
>   repo, and allows the user to update the device's location settings
>   using a location dialog.
>
> Uses the SettingsApi to ensure that the device's system settings are
>   properly configured for the app's location needs.

---

***UPDATE 1***:

**[Google Play services, Version 7.0 (March 2015) released...](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)**

> **Location settings** - While the FusedLocationProviderApi combines multiple sensors to give you the optimal location, the accuracy of the
>   location your app receives still depends greatly on the settings
>   enabled on the device (GPS, wifi, airplane mode, and others). Using
>   the new SettingsApi class, you can bring up a Location Settings dialog
>   which displays a one-touch control for users to change their settings
>   without leaving your app.

Using the **[public interface SettingsApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html)**

> - Determine if the relevant system settings are enabled on the device to carry out the desired location request.
> - Optionally, invoke a dialog that allows the user to enable the necessary location settings with a single tap.

---

---

Leaving the previous part for reference:
***Update/Answer***
For everybody looking for this answer, **Google Play Services 7.0**
It Adds APIs For Detecting Places And Connecting To Nearby Devices, Improves On Mobile Ads, Fitness Data, Location Settings, And More

> In Google Play services 7.0, we’re introducing a standard mechanism to
>   check that the necessary location settings are enabled for a given
>   LocationRequest to succeed. If there are possible improvements, you
>   can display a one touch control for the user to change their settings
>   without leaving your app.
>
> [image: exactly this]
>
> This API provides a great opportunity to make for a much better user
>   experience, particularly if location information is critical to the
>   user experience of your app such as was the case with Google Maps when
>   they integrated the Location Settings dialog and saw a dramatic
>   increase in the number of users in a good location state.

**Source:** [Android developers blog: Google Play services 7.0 - Places Everyone!](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html)

> **SDK Coming Soon!**
>   We will be rolling out Google Play services 7.0 over
>   the next few days. Expect an update to this blog post, published
>   documentation, and the availability of the SDK once the rollout is
>   completed.

will update the programmatic l-o-c after implementation

Comment: i need new SDK download can you add link ??

Comment: basically your SDK manager -> Extras -> Google Play Services , update that and it will be included in your library project

Comment: The first link above is broken.

Comment: @patrickandroid thanks, updated link, haven't gone through the code

Answer (score 22):

Based on @user2450263 notes above, here are some snippets,

```
/**
 * Prompt user to enable GPS and Location Services
 * @param mGoogleApiClient
 * @param activity
 */
public static void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                activity, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And use it like,

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 34992, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient, MyActivity.this);
```

Basically your user will get a prompt like this, where they can enable Location in High Accuracy mode without going in the settings
[image: Turn on GPS]

Comment: googleclient api is deprecated, what is another solution and i want to turn on gps and get latitude,longitude without going to setting.please guide me about this

Answer (score 2):

I have solution, tested on Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow, on button event `OnClick` call the void:

```
private void openGPSSettings() {
    //Get GPS now state (open or closed)
    boolean gpsEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(getContentResolver(), LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (gpsEnabled) {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, 0);
    } else {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, 3);
    }
}
```

Android needs to have USB debugging enabled or be rooted. Execute the command below in `adb shell` (from a root shell on the device or from a computer connected by USB if the device is not rooted):

```
pm grant com.example.application.test android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Add these permissions in app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Not all phones are rooted. This is not a feasible solution.

Comment: This does not work with systemless rooted android 6 devices, does it? The app needs to be a system app as well, correct? I'm talking about android 6 and above only...

Comment: why is it not feasible? Works for me. I need for testing to switch between location modes, so I installed my app on UNrooted Galaxy S6, run "adb shell pm grant <my package> android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS", it does the job (phone pops up dialog for the first time but then, mode consistently gets switched to "High accuracy" mode, ).

Comment: It's not a viable solution for most Android apps though.