# how to show location setting dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, location, google-play-services

From the google i/o 2015 I have learned that there is a new dialog in google play service where user doesnt need to exit the current app to turn on location. here is the image below that shows how it looks like:

[image]

now my question is, how can I implement this in my project? I have searched but didnt find any valid answer, please help!

Comment: Use `SettingsApi` on in the Play Services SDK: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759454/enabling-location-with-mode-high-accuracy-or-battery-saving-without-user-needing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [google service documetation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) for api's
and you will find everything well documented.
For your request i would suggest to use the [LocationSettingsRequest.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder) to reach your goal.

I have found an example by Kai in stackoverflow: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872703/2614938)

Comment: someone specifically looking for SettingsApi page, please refer [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Kotlin**

This solution is applicable for both `Activity` and `Fragment` by doing one following change:

**For Activity** `resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING)`

**For Fragment**
`startIntentSenderForResult(resolvableApiException.resolution.intentSender, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING, null, 0, 0,0,null)`

By using [LocationSettingsResponse](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsResponse) this task can be achieved.

inside [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)

```
    private fun checkLocationSetting()
        {
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            locationRequest.apply {
                priority=LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                interval = 5000
                fastestInterval = 2000
            }
    
            val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true)
    
            val result: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(applicationContext)
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    
            result.addOnCompleteListener {
                try{
                    val response: LocationSettingsResponse = it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, "checkSetting: GPS On")
                }catch(e:ApiException){
    
                    when(e.statusCode){
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->{
                            val resolvableApiException = e as ResolvableApiException
// for fragment change below line to: startIntentSenderForResult(resolvableApiException.resolution.intentSender, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING, null, 0, 0,0,null)
                            resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING)
                            Log.d(TAG, "checkSetting: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED")
                        }
    
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                            // USER DEVICE DOES NOT HAVE LOCATION OPTION
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when(requestCode)
        {
            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING ->{
                when(resultCode){
                    Activity.RESULT_OK->{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ->{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is Required to use this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Link to complete code [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Link to complete code [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)