# Enable GPS using Dialog Box

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to enable GPS settings using dialog box with the user confirmation.

here is the code

```
    public void turnGPSOn() {
            LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean enabled = service
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (!enabled) {
                      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this);
                      alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Enable it?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
/** Here it's leading to GPS setting options*/
                                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                                    }
                                });
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
```

Above code will lead the user to gps setting options.But i have seen in many apps(recent apps) where after confirmation gps setting will be enabled to High-Accuracy automatically.

My Question is i need to enable GPS setting to Battery Saving mode(or any other) after user confirmation(Dialog 'yes') without going to GPS settings.

```
MinSDK:9
TargetSDK:23
BuildToolVer:23.0.1
```

Regards.

Comment: for ref, may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759454/enabling-location-with-mode-high-accuracy-or-battery-saving-without-user-needing

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GoogleApiClient` for that.

```
  private static GoogleApiClient client;
  private  Location mLastLocation;
```

Also implement necessary interfaces.

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
```

I have implemented these above `interfaces`

initialize `GoogleApiClient` in `OnCreate` like this. Add necessary `Api`s.

```
  if (client == null) {
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .enableAutoManage(context, 0, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
```

You can set accuracy by  setting priority in the location Request.

These are different priorities.

```
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER
```

In the onConnected method make the location request.

The onConnected method is available in `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` interface.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(client, builder.build());

    if (result != null) {
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a optionsDialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the optionsDialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 1000);
                            }
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the optionsDialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> `startResolutionForResult()` This function shows the dialog for
>   enabling GPS without going to the Location Settings

1000 is the REQUEST_CODE

And retrieve the location in onActivity Result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == 1000)) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
        Log.e("location", mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ":" + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me check with this code but I am not using google map and i think above code will make location setting to High-Accuracy.  My application is a background app which needs minimal info about location. Is there any way to set location setting to Battery saving mode automatically?

Comment: You can set the priority of the Location Request to set battery saving mode. Check the edited answer

Comment: @Boss so glad I found this. How can I keep popping the dialog if the user pressed no ?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel you can check that in the `onActivityResult`. Check for the resultcode `RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: @Boss and what should I put inside that ? `status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 1000);` or the entire onConnected ?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel The `onConnected` method is called by the system. So we just call the `startResolutionForResult()` method.

Comment: @Emil in fragment I am not getting onActivityResult called, I get it in activity instead.. I can take the value from activity to fragment I know but is it a way to make it work in fragment it self.. ?

Comment: @AalapPatel I don't think its possible. You have to bypass your ``onActivityResult`` to your fragment.

``public void startResolutionForResult (Activity activity, int requestCode)`` takes Activity as a parameter.
And its documentation says as below:
An Activity context to use to resolve the issue. The activity's onActivityResult method will be invoked after the user is done. If the resultCode is RESULT_OK, the application should try to connect again.

Comment: @Emil Thank you, this makes sense.