# how to change the location mode to "high accuracy/battery saving" form it default mode(device only)

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-gps, google-location-services

I'm trying to implement a google map for getting current location using this tutorial

[android google map tutorial](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/)

The problem is ,It is not getting my current location untill I have started my device's google map and grant permission to access google location services.
After this my application also get my current location. And it's working fine untill location is on in the device.
And when location is turned off it's again need to started device's google map and grant permission for google location services.

I have already generate the key according to instructions.

I'm found the problem in device location mode.when I'm changing device mode to high accuracy/battery saving manually, it works fine.

**So how to change the location mode to "high accuracy/battery saving" form it default mode(device only) programmatically**

Here is the Activity code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }
}
```

here is the manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.envent_pc03.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />-->
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: on which device you are running these ?

Comment: not sure if you can(should) do that without user's knowledge, though the neat way is to [prompt a user and let it be enabled without redirection or extra navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759454/enabling-location-with-mode-high-accuracy-or-battery-saving-without-user-needing/29002760#29002760)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before requesting location updates, you need to check for correct location settings as per your requirement.

Create a LocationSettingsRequest.Builder and add all of the LocationRequests that the app will be using:

```
 LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
```

Check whether location settings are satisfied, using

```
PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
         LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleClient, builder.build());
```

When the PendingResult returns, the client can check the location settings by looking at the status code from the LocationSettingsResult object.

```
 result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
         final Status status = result.getStatus();
         final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
         switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                 // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                 // requests here.
                 ...
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                 // a dialog.
                 try {
                     // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                     // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                     status.startResolutionForResult(
                         MapsActivity.this,
                         REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                 } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                     // Ignore the error.
                 }
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                 // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                 ...
                 break;
         }
     }
 });
```

The result of the dialog will be returned via onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);
     switch (requestCode) {
         case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
             switch (resultCode) {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     // All required changes were successfully made
                     ...
                     break;
                 case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                     // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                     ...
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
             }
             break;
     }
 }
```

For reference, read [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) document which explains the case very well.

Alternatively, you can directly redirect the user to location settings page.

```
int locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(activityUnderTest.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
```

Check [location_mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE) for possible return values.

```
if(locationMode == LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY) {
   //request location updates
} else { //redirect user to settings page
   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: how to ask permission again if user deny the pop up dailog

Comment: @atishr Call the permission asking method in `case RESULT_CANCELED:` in `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationrequest = new LocationRequest().create();
    locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationrequest.setInterval(1000);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mgoogleApi, locationrequest, this);
    Toast.makeText(context,"Location Connected and ready to publish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your google map from xml whether it will class or google support map cause you are using fragments so.