# How to Accurate FusedApi between 10 meter

Tags: android, geolocation, fusedlocationproviderapi

Incorrect Fused Location API location LAtitiude Longitude.Is there any API to provide accurate location?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759454/enabling-location-mode-high-accuracy-or-battery-saving-programmatically-withou 
try this

Comment: You aren't going to get more accurate than about 10m.  The hardware in most phones just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want to snap to the road or use a Map Matching algorithm. For that task you can use e.g.

- [GoogleMapsRoads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap?hl=de),
- [MapBox Map Matching API](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-matching/)
- [Graphhopper Map-Matching](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching)

Answer (score -1):

Use this and you will get precision upto 14+ decimal places.

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, new MyLocationListener());